# Target a specific switch case

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a generic template function that will act as a layout utility for the app. I'm planning to insert content to the left and right columns as needed. I am struggling to find a way to target a specific switch case.

```
function Template({state, props}) {
  switch(state) {
    case 'halfhalf':
        return 
        <div className="halfhalf">
          <div className="SplitPane-left">
            {props.left}
          </div>
          <div className="SplitPane-right">
            {props.right}
          </div>
        </div>;
    case 'sixfour':
        return 
          <div className="sixfour">
            <div className="SplitPane-left">
              {props.left}
            </div>
            <div className="SplitPane-right">
              {props.right}
            </div>
          </div>;
    default:
        return null;
  }
}
```

And this is how I plan to use it:

```
function About() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>About</h1>
      <Template 
        left={
          <h1>This is it Left column</h1>
        }
        right={
          <h1>This is it Right column</h1>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by saying "I am struggling to find a way to target a specific switch case" can you give more details?

Comment: If case="sixfour" return ...  
Else if case="halfhalf" return ...  
else if ....  
else if ...

Comment: that is clear but not how you are handling the state part? and what is the help required in little more detail?

Comment: How can I call and display one of the switch cases using: <Template />?

Comment: ok, why not use props instead to pass like `<Template option="halfhalf" />` and switch on `props.option` will this help?

Comment: When you do a call like this, the best way is to pass the values in `props`